# Magento template variable $customer

Tags: templates, magento, magento-1.4

I see this variable `{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}` in the file `app/locale/en_US/template/email/wishlist_share.html`.

Can someone tell me a list of properties for the $customer variable?  I want to be able to access things like email, address, tax/vat number etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find a list on the [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index#email_variables), make sure that you test it thoroughly, I've had some inconsistent results depending on the context that the email template is sent from.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I asked a related question about template if statements here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements  would you happen to know anything about it as well?