# Magento 1 if statements in email template

Tags: email, templates, magento

I'm trying to get a conditional to work in a Magento email template, but for whatever reason, I can't get the 'if' to evaluate to true.  In my template, I have:

```
Shipping Method:{{var order.shipping_method}}<br /><br />
{{if order.shipping_method=="wsastorepickup_wsastorepickup"}}
   Run this<br /><br />
{{else}}
    WTF, OVER?<br /><br />
{{/if}}
```

When Magento sends the email it has:

```
Shipping Method:wsastorepickup_wsastorepickup

WTF, OVER?
```

I've tried it with and without the 'var' in the conditional.  What am I missing?

Comment: Further testing has this outputting 'Fail':
{{if "test" == "test"}}
Success<br /><br />
{{else}}
Fail <br /><br />
{{/if}}

Comment: The question has been asked before: [Check out the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4797394/8897789)